# Range-based for loop with boost::adaptor::indexed

Tags: c++11, boost-range

The C++11 range-based for loop dereferences the iterator. Does that mean that it makes no sense to use it with `boost::adaptors::indexed`? Example:

```
boost::counting_range numbers(10,20);
for(auto i : numbers | indexed(0)) {
  cout << "number = " i 
  /* << " | index = " << i.index() */ // i is an integer!
  << "\n";
}
```

I can always use a counter but I like indexed iterators.

- Is it possible to use them somehow with range-based for loops?
- What is the idiom for using range-based loops with an index? (just a plain counter?)

Comment: `indexed` sucks because it adds the `index()` method to the *iterator*, not the value returned from dereferencing the iterator. :/

Comment: @Xeo Indeed. Every now and then I need the index of the element in the range. First I feel bad about it. Then, I introduce a counter. If the container can be easily accessed with a plain old loop, I feel bad again and rewrite the range-based loop into a plain old loop.

Comment: as Xeo mentioned boost indexed is not good for this. If you dont mind switching libraries theres a few C++ range libraries based on python's itertools, such as: https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/

Comment: Note: this is fixed since **Boost 1.56** (released August 2014); the element is indirected behind a  `value_type` with `index()` and `value()` member functions.

Comment: @gnzlbg, are you able to correct `boost::adaptor::indexed` to `boost::adaptors::indexed`, as it took a while for me to realize that `s` was missing?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in Boost 1.56 (released August 2014); the element is indirected behind a `value_type` with `index()` and `value()` member functions.

Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e95bdff0a9d371ea

```
auto numbers = boost::counting_range(10, 20);
for (auto i : numbers | boost::adaptors::indexed())
    std::cout << "number = " << i.value()
        << " | index = " << i.index() << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems more useful when iterating over collection, where you may need the index position (to print the item number if not for anything else):

```
  #include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

  std::vector<std::string> list = {"boost", "adaptors", "are", "great"};
  for (auto v: list | boost::adaptors::indexed(0)) {
    printf("%ld: %s\n", v.index(), v.value().c_str());
  }
```

Prints:

```
0: boost
1: adaptors
2: are
3: great
```

Any innovation for simply iterating over integer range is strongly challenged by the classic for loop, still very strong competitor:

```
for (int a = 10; a < 20; a++)
```

While this can be twisted up in a number of ways, it is not so easy to propose something that is obviously much more readable.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer (as everyone in the comments mentioned) is "right, it makes no sense."  I have also found this annoying.  Depending your programming style, you might like the "zipfor" package I wrote (just a header): [from github](https://github.com/cshelton/zipfor/)

It allows syntax like

```
std::vector v;
zipfor(x,i eachin v, icounter) {
   // use x as deferenced element of x
   // and i as index
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure a way to use the ranged-based for syntax and have to resort to the "zipfor" macro :(

The header was originally designed for things like

```
std::vector v,w;
zipfor(x,y eachin v,w) {
   // x is element of v
   // y is element of w (both iterated in parallel)
}
```

and

```
std::map m;
mapfor(k,v eachin m)
   // k is key and v is value of pair in m
```

My tests on g++4.8 with full optimizations shows that the resulting code is no slower than writing it by hand.